ispell not working with Hunspell on Doom Emacs
So, I used to use aspell, but now I want to use hunspell. I'm a Doom Emacs user, so I there might be a specific setting I need to set that I haven't set. Not sure.
I have hunspell installed with a GB dictionary, and I have removed aspell from machine. My system locale is set to en_GB.UTF-8. Any time I run a command which invokes ispell (ispell-region, ispell-buffer or ispell-word), I get the following error in the message buffer: ispell-find-hunspell-dictionaries: Can’t find Hunspell dictionary with a .aff affix file. hunspell works from the command line, but not in Doom.

You need to use this expression in your init.el file: (spell +flyspell +hunspell)
and read before that this document <your-doomemacs-folder>/modules/checkers/spell/README.orgwhere is specified how to install (depend on your OS). You must specify (mandatory)
the +flyspell package.
